# Workbook_BeforeSave not recognized

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file with a some macros, one of them is *Workbook_BeforeSave*

It has been working good so far, but suddenly the file stopped working. I get the error message

```
"Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)"
```

I even deleted the code inside and still get the error. Now the code is like this:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
 End Sub
```

Older versions of this file are working fine. I mean, before the problem started, I saved the file with a  different name. The vba has not changed, the 2 files only differ in data. One of those files works ok, the other shows this problem.

The tools:

Visual Basic for Applications

Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library

OLE Automation

Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

are checked

The Office version is Office 365

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is this a compile error, or did you get it at runtime? If runtime, on which line?

Comment: The file was already compiled and working, but now it seems to have a compile error. If I delete the Workbook_BeforeSave sub altogether, I get another error in a Worksheet_Change sub that used to work properly.

Comment: Just to be clear do you get this error when you save the workbook, use Debug > Compile, or when running a Sub?

Comment: Debug --> Compile. But if I save the book, I also get the error, so the Event is properly triggered

Comment: Maybe it's corruption, you could try copying all objects and code to a new workbook.

Comment: @Absinthe That works, thanks. Just wondering how the file became corrupt, it is the second time it happens. The company just installed Microsoft Azure. I've been searching and I didn't find anything similar, maybe it is just coincidental. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just a fact of life with MS Office unfortunately, the older and more frequently used Excel and Access files are the more they're prone to corruption. A quick fix is to save the workbook as xlsb then back into the original format but a better one is moving to a new book as you did. For large old files in frequent use I tend to do this every six months as a maintenance activity.